# Why does the marker-start in my SVG path not show in the browser (but in the generated PNG)?

Tags: svg

Can someone please tell me, why the left arrow head in the following file shows correctly in the generated PNG, but not in the browser?

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SVG_double_arrow_with_marker-start_and_marker-end.svg

In Firefox it is just not there, and in Chrome I see it pointing to the bottom right instead of left.

These are the two markers:

```
<marker id="arrowend" viewBox="0 0 13 10" refX="2" refY="5" markerWidth="3.5" markerHeight="3.5" orient="auto">
    <path d="M 0 0  C 0 0, 3 5, 0 10   L 0 10  L 13 5" fill="red"/>
</marker>

<marker id="arrowstart" viewBox="0 0 -13 -10" refX="-2" refY="-5" markerWidth="-3.5" markerHeight="-3.5" orient="auto">
    <path d="M 0 0  C 0 0, -3 -5, 0 -10   L 0 -10  L -13 -5" fill="red"/>
</marker>
```

My solution based on the hint below:

```
<marker id="arrowstart" viewBox="0 0 13 10" refX="11" refY="5" markerWidth="3.5" markerHeight="3.5" orient="auto">
    <path d="M 13 0  C 13 0, 10 5, 13 10   L 13 10  L 0 5" fill="red"/>
</marker>
```

So I changed the actual path. All my attempts to just mirror it failed, so for me this was the best solution.

This is where I put it in action, BTW: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Full_octahedral_group;_single_elements;_signed_perm_mat,_perm_mat_and_cube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A viewBox with [negative width and height is invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute). The contents of invalid viewBoxes do not render.

If Chrome renders arrowstart in any way, that's a Chrome bug. Whatever png generator you're using is clearly also buggy.

Here's one way to get the arrows on both ends, at least on browsers that support orient="auto-start-reverse"

```html
<svg  width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 50">
    <defs>
        <marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 13 10" refX="2" refY="5" markerWidth="3.5" markerHeight="3.5" orient="auto-start-reverse">
            <path d="M 0 0  C 0 0, 3 5, 0 10   L 0 10  L 13 5" fill="red"/>
        </marker>
    </defs>

    <line x1="25" y1="25" x2="175" y2="25" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" marker-start="url(#arrow)" marker-end="url(#arrow)"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: That works in the browser, but most of the time in the rendered PNG both arrow heads point right: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SVG_double_arrow_with_auto-start-reverse.svg